# i want to add variable into json object in arduino

Tags: json, socket.io, arduino-esp8266

so i have a socket io app, i need to emit json but have no idea how to insert variable into json object

this the example from : https://github.com/timum-viw/socket.io-client#emit

```
socket.emit("plainString", "\"this is a plain string\"");
socket.emit("jsonObject", "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");
```

and this is my code :

```
char* variable = "this is a string";

socket.emit("jsonObject", "{\"foo\":\"variable\"}");
```

result in socket io

```
[
"foo":"variable"
]
```

expected result :

```
 [
    "foo":"this is a string"
    ]
```

Comment: https://arduinojson.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
void SendSocket(String socketname,String foo,String bar){
  String Data = "{\"_foo\":\"" + foo + "\",\"_bar\":\"" + bar + "\"}";
  socket.emit(socketname.c_str(), Data.c_str());
}
```

And here is how to use it

```
SendSocket("jsonObject","this is foo","this is bar");
```

And this is the code to catch the event from Arduino (in server):

```
socket.on("jsonObject",function data(){
console.log(data);
});
```

The result will be:

```
[
_foo:"this is foo",
_bar:"this is bar"
]
```